# Alternative for UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipickerview

Is there any other method for a SLOT-MACHINE app? This because a UIPICKER method doesn't have a slow animation effect.

Comment: I suggesting TableView. Load all data into it instead picker and any one can select from it.

Comment: and then? can a spin action be applied to it?

Comment: @Kobe You dont need a spin action. In UITableView You have horizontal scrollers enabled. So you can use it without any limitations .

Comment: @R.A My project should be button enabled. when a user touch a button or the uitableview part it spins. how will I do it?

Comment: @Kobe Use Custom cell class to add a button in UITableViewCell and use gesture recognizer to recognize your touch to scroll the tableview functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using `CALayer` animation.

Your main slotMachineView layer's class will need to be `CATransformLayer` to allow 3D transforms of the sublayers.

Let's say you have 10 square images that represent the symbols on the reel. For each of your images, create a `CALayer` who's contents property is one of your images. Then to each layer you'll need to apply 2 transforms:

- First you'll need to rotate each layer (2 * PI) / 10 about its X axis
- Then translate some distance (which you'll need to calculate) along
  the Z axis.

Now add these layers to your view's layer. You should now see a get "cylinder" of images around the X axis.

To rotate the cylinder you'll need to adjust the first transform - either with a `CAAnimation`  or by using a timer and adjusting the X axis rotation by an offset she the timer fires.

I'll leave it to you to figure out the full implementation details - but here's some code to load and create an initial "reel"

```
    int imageCount = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
        // Load image from the bundle

        NSString * fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Image-%d", i];
        NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: fileName ofType: @"jpeg"];

        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filePath];

        // Create a layer with the image as content - My image size was 60x60

        CALayer * imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
        imageLayer.bounds = (CGRect){CGPointZero, {60.0, 60.0}};
        imageLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
        imageLayer.position = (CGPoint){CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds)};

        // Set the initial image transform - I've hardcoded the translate along the
        // z-axis to 150, but this will vary depending on the number of images
        // and their size - you'll need to do some maths to work it out... sines or 
        // cosines or somesuch
        CGFloat angle = (2.0 * M_PI) / imageCount * i;
        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, 0.0, 150.0);  
        imageLayer.transform = transform;

        [self.layers addObject: imageLayer];

        [self.view.layer addSublayer: imageLayer];
    }
}
```

To rotate it, all you need to do is change the rotation part of the transform. For extra credit, you could add an increasing shadow to the layers as they move away from the centre.

Comment: So i'll put the images in an NSArray/NSMutable Array, and then transform their layer?

Comment: Good idea. UIPickerView just looks like it has shadow gradient on the top and bottom to give the illusion of a wheel, combined with the outer graphics. The numbers/text on the wheels don't transform.

Comment: @bandejapaisa so what's the best way to do? CALAYER?

Comment: This suggestion by @Ashley Mills is great, but it's probably the most complex. Obviously I think my suggestion is the best :-). There are many ways to do it, there isn't wrong or right way or a better way.

Comment: Yeah, i think its a bit complex. But i think you're both Great! :) thanks for the help. I'll try what you all suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: What if I'm going to import an image in a folder/bundle. how will I transform them in a cylinder type?

Comment: how will I import images from the photo library or camera?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `UIImageView` for each digit/symbol, and animate the movement of the images that yo display. Using `UIPicker` there would be limited to letters and digits; with `UIImageView` you could add other typical slot-machine visuals, such as cherries, etc.

Comment: how would I able to apply a spin effect?

Comment: @Kobe You would need to implement it yourself, for example by applying Core Animation. This is probably the whole point of this assignment.

Comment: where can I store the images for the UIImageView?

Comment: @Kobe you add them to you Xcode project, and mark for inclusion inthe application bundle. You should be able to find multiple examples of doing both these things.

Comment: Can I use NSArray/NSMutableArray for those images?

Comment: @Kobe absolutely - once you load your images from the bundle, you are free to store them in any way you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Are we doing your homework?

Use vertical UIScrollViews side by side, have paging enabled, UIImageViews for the views.

It will look flat by default - but it would be functionally equivalent.

You'd need a bit of Core Animation / Core Graphics to make it look more like the UIPickerView.

Comment: Yes, you can call methods on UIScrollView to scroll it automatically, and you can have it continuously scroll.

Comment: Can I Use NSArray/NSMutable Array for the UIImageViews? so I can store my images?